# Hyperledger Genesis Block

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Following a guide, doesn't tell me how to fix this. Help?

```
$ ./byfn.sh -m generate
Generating certs and genesis block for with channel 'mychannel' and CLI timeout of '10000'
Continue (y/n)? y
proceeding ...
/c/Users/Jake/Documents/Hyperledger Project/fabric-samples/bin/cryptogen

##########################################################
##### Generate certificates using cryptogen tool #########
##########################################################
org1.example.com
org2.example.com

./byfn.sh: line 164: cd: too many arguments
sed: -e expression #1, char 85: unterminated `s' command
./byfn.sh: line 166: cd: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/: No such file or directory
./byfn.sh: line 168: cd: too many arguments
sed: -e expression #1, char 85: unterminated `s' command
/c/Users/Jake/Documents/Hyperledger Project/fabric-samples/bin/configtxgen
##########################################################
#########  Generating Orderer Genesis block ##############
##########################################################
2017-09-09 20:16:32.117 PDT [common/configtx/tool] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2017-09-09 20:16:32.138 PDT [common/configtx/tool] doOutputBlock -> INFO 002 Generating genesis block
2017-09-09 20:16:32.139 PDT [common/configtx/tool] doOutputBlock -> INFO 003 Writing genesis block
2017-09-09 20:16:32.139 PDT [common/configtx/tool] main -> CRIT 004 Error on outputBlock: Error writing genesis block: open ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block: The system cannot find the path specified.
Failed to generate orderer genesis block...
```

Don't know what CRIT 004 Error means or what path its talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably hitting:

https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5618 - Hyperledge Fabric Samples directory cannot contain a space

since your script is under:

> /c/Users/Jake/Documents/Hyperledger Project/fabric-samples/bin/cryptogen

Why don't you rename `Hyperledger Project` to something without spaces like `HyperledgerProject`.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 try to generate the genesis block in missing folder:

```
$./byfn.sh down
$../bin/cryptogen generate --config=./crypto-config.yaml
Org1.example.com
Org2.example.com
$../bin/configtxgen --profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis –outputBlock./channel- 
artifacts/genesis.block
$./byfn.sh generate
$./byfn.sh up
```